# python multiprocessing pool.apply_async

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

How to make python multiprocessing code more robust to increased data size?
I'm submitting jobs using pool.apply_async for each chromosome, simulation and split. 
Each split can have at most 100K lines. In this way I'm making each job with equal size. 
And accumulating result that comes from pool.apply_async

```
    numofProcesses = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=numofProcesses,maxtasksperchild=10)

    all_result1={}
    all_result2={}

    def accumulate(result):
     result1=result[0]
     result2=result[1]
     accumulate(resulst1,all_result1)
     accumulate(resulst2,all_result2)

    for each chr:
     for each sim:
      for each chrbased_simbased_split:
         pool.apply_async(func, args=(too,many,),callback=accumulate_result)

  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

However, it seems that too many pool.apply_async calls are done.
e.g: Starting from (chr1,sim1), already job call for (chr1,sim97) is done, whereas result for (chr1, sim3) is yet returned.
Therefore too many jobs active in the pool consuming a huge memory.

Is there are a way to send jobs in a more controlled way: as they are completed, otherwise pool.apply_async consumes huge memory (~50 GB) and it will give memory error very soon?

Hope I can get some help.
Thanks.

Comment: _However, it seems that too many pool.apply_async calls are done. e.g: Starting from (chr1,sim1), already job call for (chr1,sim97) is done, whereas result for (chr1, sim3) is yet returned._ Isn't that how `apply_async` works? _Is there are a way to send jobs in a more controlled way: as they are completed_ Do you care about the order in which the input is processed and returned? It looks like we're missing some important/relevant parts of the code, too. As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: No order is needed in processing the input and in accumulating the result.

Comment: Then you can use `Pool.imap_unordered()`, unless you're doing something particular with the callback.

Comment: pool.apply_async was good because you do not need to prepare an iterable of input, you provide  your input for only one job. Problem with pool.apply_async became the huge memory consumption. Lots of jobs with their input waiting and very litttle results are accumulated. With imap_unordered, I need to prepare an iterable for input and what will be its memory usage? Any idea?

Comment: _With imap_unordered, I need to prepare an iterable for input and what will be its memory usage?_ You can iterate over the result directly, which should yield values as they arrive. You wrote _Lots of jobs with their input waiting and very litttle results are accumulated_, can you share some more information on the architecture of the program? What do you do with the result?

Comment: imap_unordered seems to be very slow. Is there a way use a queue for jobs, a process to put jobs in the queue as long as there is data left and jobs in the queue is less than a value and pool of workers to do the jobs? I mean combination of pool and queue and process to fill the queue. In this way,   there won't be a lot of data sent and waiting to be processed and increasing memory usage.

Comment: Is the `accumulate` function time-consuming? It’s a bit difficult to tell what’s going on because the code is so abstract, there are multiple things which could be done.

Comment: Accumulate updates dictionaries with worker process returned dictionaries. It uses  for loops to do this accumulation.

Comment: Is that where the issue mostly lies? Have you done any profiling? In any case, you could have the results of each job sent to a queue, and the `accumulate` function reading from that queue, which would limit the amount of work being performed at the same time. It might also be a good idea to tweak the number of processes.